# Is there any way to search through comments?

Tags: support, comments

I'm trying to find a particular comment thread on an old post of mine.  Unfortunately, the search box in the top-right only searches through answers, not comments, and Googling doesn't help because most comments end up hidden behind the "show comments" link.  Is there any way to search for it?

Comment: No idea who voted to close this as off topic, but asking for support with the site's features is _perfectly_ on topic on Meta Programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that I can think of is to use [the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/). Comments are second-class citizens and aren't searchable, not well-index by Google, and extended discussions can be cleaned up with no warning (moderators are alerted to any post with large numbers of comments and can remove any comments that are noisy).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/102409/search-comments).  If you're logged in it should autofill the UserId parameter.  The text parameter uses SQL syntax.  For example, if you want to search for "SQL" anywhere in your comment, enter "%SQL%".